# TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable (Tensorforce DQN Tutorial)

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I am trying to do a tensorforce tutorial with a DQN algorithm, but I am running into some errors. It seems that tensorforce has been updated since this tutorial was written, so I am trying to figure things out on my own with the documentation. Anywho, here is my code.

```
import logging

from tensorforce.environments.openai_gym import OpenAIGym
from tensorforce.agents import DQNAgent
from tensorforce.execution import Runner

# def main():
gym_id = 'CartPole-v0'
max_episodes = 10000
max_timesteps = 1000
total_memory = 100

env = OpenAIGym(gym_id)
network_spec = [
    dict(type='dense', size=32, activation='tanh'),
    dict(type='dense', size=32, activation='tanh')
]

agent = DQNAgent(
    # states_spec=env.states,
    # actions_spec=env.actions,
    states=env.states,
    actions=env.actions,
    # network_spec=network_spec,
    batch_size=64,
    memory=total_memory  <-- Here is where my error is coming from.
)

runner = Runner(agent, env)

report_episodes = 10

def episode_finished(r):
    if r.episode % report_episodes == 0:
        logging.info("Finished episode {ep} after {ts} timesteps".format(ep=r.episode, ts=r.timestep))
        logging.info("Episode reward: {}".format(r.episode_rewards[-1]))
        logging.info("Average of last 100 rewards: {}".format(sum(r.episode_rewards[-100:]) / 100))
    return True

print("Starting {agent} for Environment '{env}'".format(agent=agent, env=env))

runner.run(max_episodes, max_timesteps, episode_finished=episode_finished)
runner.close()

print("Learning finished. Total episodes: {ep}".format(ep=runner.episode))

# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     main
```

With the error originating from

```
memory=total_memory
```

The documentation found [here](https://github.com/tensorforce/tensorforce/blob/master/tensorforce/agents/dqn.py) says that memory is required and that it must be an int>0, so I am confused. Any help would be sweet.

**EDIT**
Here is the traceback code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 19, in <module>
    agent = DQNAgent(
  File "/home/dskinner/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorforce/agents/dqn.py", line 217, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/dskinner/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorforce/agents/tensorforce.py", line 441, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/dskinner/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorforce/agents/agent.py", line 243, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/dskinner/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorforce/agents/recorder.py", line 50, in __init__
    if 'type' in states or 'shape' in states:
TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable
```

Comment: I don't think that line is the problem; the problem is happening as a result of constructing the `DQNAgent` object, and so the error is pointing to the line where the object creation happens. If you posted the **full** stacktrace as a part of your [mre] then we could maybe figure out what the actual issue is more easily.

Comment: I am sorry it is taking me so long. I was using google colab so I had to do some configuring on my local machine to get the traceback.

Comment: Does `states=env.states()` inside `DQNAgent` solve your problem?

Comment: @enzo changing from what I have to ```states=env.states()``` and ```actions=env.actions()``` fixed that problem. Now there are just more problems to work through, lol. Thank you!